# Is it possible to set the title of a toolbar item using a content view as a control in the master detailed page?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

[image]

I have Master-Detailed Page, which inside the content page I have a content view which I use as a Bottom navigation bar which has items/buttons of which when one of the button is clicked I want it to display my timer on the toolbar.

How can I achieve this?

Below is the content view control that has the command that triggers the timer
to start.

```
private static CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource;

public partial class LandingPageBottomNavigationBarView : ContentView
{    
    public LandingPageBottomNavigationBarView (string active)
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        BindingContext = new 
        ViewModels.LandingPageBottomNavigationBarViewModel(active);
        _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

     }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
    {
        base.OnBindingContextChanged();

        stckIconPage4.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer
        {
            Command = new Command(_ =>
            {
                 CancellationTokenSource cts = _cancellationTokenSource; // safe copy
                var startAt = DateTime.Now;


                Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () =>
                {
                    if (cts.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                        {

                            TimeSpan _TimeSpan = DateTime.Now - startAt;

                           Application.Current.Properties["ClockInTimeSpan"] = _TimeSpan;


                        });

                        return true;
                    }

                });
            })
        });
     }
 }
```

Below is the content Page that has the toolbar item which I want my timer to be displayed and updated as soon as the user taps the clockin control which I do on the TimerClockIn method which isn't the correct way I'm doing it so your is much aprreciated.

```
public partial class HomeLandingPageDetail : ContentPage
{
     public HomeLandingPageDetail()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        GridFooter.Children.Add(new UserControls.LandingPageBottomNavigationBarView(Constants.MenuConst.MenuPage2));

        TimerClockIn();
    }

    private void TimerClockIn()
    {

        var startAt = DateTime.Now;
        var isContainCancelationRequested = Application.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("IsCancellationRequested"); //Application.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("ClockInTimeSpan");
        var isContainClockInTimeSpan = Application.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("ClockInTimeSpan");

        if (isContainClockInTimeSpan)
        {
            Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () =>
            {


                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {

                    TimeSpan _TimeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(Application.Current.Properties["ClockInTimeSpan"].ToString());//DateTime.Now - startAt;

                    ToolbarTimer.Text = _TimeSpan.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");

                });

                return true;
            });
        }

    }
```

}

Comment: Could you elaborate what your actual problem is? What have you tried to achieve what you want and where are you stuck? Adding your XAML (and C#) could be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `Title View` of xamarin form. Just place your view in the `TitleView`. 
A usage example is like this(I just show a Image ):

```
<NavigationPage.TitleView>
    <Image Source="img123" WidthRequest="20" HeightRequest="20"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
           HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
</NavigationPage.TitleView>
```

For more details, you can refer to official document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/navigation-titleview/